# How can I connect to SAP using sapnwrfc library?

Tags: c#, saprfc, jco, netweaver, dllnotfoundexception

Our software is written in C# and needs to connect to SAP. As some of our customers use older versions of SAP, and others don't have SAP PI, we can't connect through webservices.

I tried to connect to SAP through the SAP NetWeaver Remote Function Call Library (`sapnwrfc.dll`) as follows:

- Add sapnwrfc.dll and the other DLLs from `NWRFC_6-20004550.SAR` (being icudt34.dll, icuin34.dll, icuuc34.dll, libicudecnumber.dll, and libsapucum.dll) to `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, to be sure that they can be found.
- In my C# code add the following in the class definition:

  ```
  [DllImport("sapnwrfc.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern void RfcInit();
  ```

  and the following in the method that should do the work:

  ```
  RfcInit();
  ```

Running this code gives a `DllNotFoundException`:

> Unable to load DLL 'sapnwrfc.dll': This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

Running the standard connect-to-C++-from-C# example:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]<br/>
public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Hello World!", "Hello Dialog", 0);
```

works fine.

Any suggestions how to make this work fine (so that we don't need to workaround this problem by writing a Java proxy using JCo)?

Comment: Good question - no idea, sorry. Tagging this as RFC additionally. If you need help with the java fallback, feel free to ask :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check with the Dependency Viewer if you are missing some DLL? I did once write a managed wrapper for the rfc library (at least part of it) and I remember having a problem with some of the rfc libraries I downloaded. One version simply did not work and I did not figure out what was wrong. Another version (older) worked just fine.

I did however have problems with the unicode library (some memory access problem that appeared randomly) so I had to switch to the non-unicode version...

If I had to do something like this again, I would very seriously consider to buy a connector:
http://www.theobald-software.com/en/products/erpconnect.htm

I cannot say if it is any good, but they seem to be around for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use SAP's ".NET Connector" (NCo3)?
See SAP note 856863 for a link to the download page and documentation.

Comment: Maybe because SAP had not published NCo3 yet back in February 2010? ;)

Comment: Hmm, that may be a valid reason... ;) But I better leave my comment now for people reading this today.

Comment: OK, that's convincing. One upvote from me for your sense of humor (and a correct answer, of course). :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to copy icudt34.dll, icuin34.dll, icuuc34.dll, libicudecnumber.dll, and libsapucum.dll to the directory of your project's bin. I had try it and it works well.